# Exception in docstring python3

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, docstring

What is a best practice to insert Exception and Exception Type in docstring in python3?

I use this pattern:

```
def get_platform(cls, platform, channel):
    """
    Get specific plafform in BotMachine list

    :param str from const in BotMachine platform: type of platform
    :param str channel: id of channel in platform
    :return: messaging platform
    :rtype: MessagingPlatform
    :raise Exception: platform not found
    """
```

Pycharm accept this format and present Exception in right way, but how i insert Except type?

And in case of use raises what is the right way?

```
"""
Comment 

:raises Exception: platform not found|argument not found
"""
```

Comment: If you're raising something other than Exception, you probably put the type you're raising there instead of Exception.

Comment: Ok, maybe, but PyCharm not recognizes the type

Answer (score 1):

```
:raises:
    Exception: Explanation here.

# or

:raises Exception: Explanation here.
```

where `Exception` can be replaced with the exception type (for ex. `ValueError: Explanation here.`)